# C# - Access denied when trying to get process's handle

Tags: c#, process, handle

I'm trying to get the handle of a process, but I get an error saying "Access Denied". Here's my code:

```
namespace Program
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IntPtr sign = Process.GetProcessesByName("thatProgram")[0].Handle;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems this works for all but this particuliar program.
Can you help me out?

Comment: Is that process running as the same user?

Comment: How could I know? Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: Well I just used the task manager and it seems they both are running as the same user indeed.

Comment: What OS you use ? Is your app x86 or x64? and what about this wakfu.exe... x86 or x64 ?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 32bit, my app and wakfu are both x86.

Comment: Did you try to split your code into `Process [] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("wakfu.exe"); IntPtr prochandle = procs[0].Handle` and check which line fails (and of course what's the details inside the `procs[]` if the first line succeeds

Comment: The account your using does not have priviledge to access the wakfu try to run it as adminstrator

Comment: Running it as administrator seems to make it work now, but it didn't yesterday. Thanks for all the answers problem fixed, even thought I don't know why it didn't work yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you try to get the handle of a System process or a process started by another user (the latter is only possible, if your application is started as admin)

Comment: That appears to be the situation in my case.  I confirm this as well.    See also SecurityAction { LinkDemand=6; }

See also 'SecurityCriticalAttribute' Class

Answer (score -1):

try  **process.MainWindowHandle** instead handle